# Graficar datos de Sql con php "HigthCharts"

Tags: php, sql, highcharts

Para que estén un poco en contexto esta es mi tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero lograr algo mas o menos así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la librería de HigthCharts. Esta es la parte de los datos:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Hombres',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Mujeres',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
    }]
});
```

Y estoy intentando algo mas o menos así:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Hombres',
        data: 
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, row['hombres']] 
        
    },
    <?php } ?> {
        
        name: 'Mujeres',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27] 
    }] 
});
```

Le asignare un dato especifico a cada cada mes, ya probé mi consulta de **SELECT** y funciona bien. Me devuelve el numero de registros que hay de hombres.

```
$grafica = "SELECT count(genero) as hombres FROM asesoria WHERE genero = 'M'";
```

Tengo mi conexión justo antes del script, no se si me puedan ayudar, que tenga mal acomodado el **While**
o algún otra librería donde podar hacer esto?

Comment: Recomiendo que primero haga el gráfico con los valores estáticos, después de estar de acuerdo con lo que ve, construya esa misma estructura pero no dentro de las funciones de higcharts, sino por fuera, y por último añade a la estructura de higcharts la variable con la estructura construida previamente. data:miVariableConEstrucutra

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, tienes razón, donde tengo mi conexión agregue el while y ya solo a una variable le acomode el row que corresponde. Ya solo en los campos de higcharts agregue la variable. Thanks!!